# VB script renaming files addind Date & Time to Name?

Tags: datetime, vbscript, copy, rename

Base Code: by Ekkehard.Horner & adapted by me
                                           I
                                         found 
                                          the 
                                          code, 
                                         thanks               all.                                                                                       Dim oShell, frequency, sFile
    Dim goFS    : Set goFS    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oSrcDir : Set oSrcDir = goFS.GetFolder("C:\Temp1")
    Dim sDstDir : sDstDir     = "C:\Temp2"
    Dim oFile, nInc, sNFSpec

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Temp1") 
Set fc = f.Files  

frequency  = 10 * 1000 
Const cnMax = 99


WScript.Sleep frequency

 theDate = Year(Now()) _
       & Right(String(2,"0") & month(Now()),2) _ 
       & Right(String(2,"0") & Day(Now()),2) 


 For Each f1 in fc 
  If right(lcase(f1.name),4) = ".pdf" then 
 theBaseName = fso.GetBaseName(f1.name)
 theExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(f1.Name) 
 f1.Move(fso.GetParentFolderName(f1.path) & "\" & theBaseName & "_" & EID & "_"    &          theDate & "." & theExtension) 
  End If
  Next

 For Each oFile In oSrcDir.Files
 If right(lcase(oFile.name),4) = ".pdf" Then 
  nInc = 0
  sNFSpec = getNewFSpec(oFile.Name, sDstDir, nInc)
  Do While goFS.FileExists(sNFSpec) And nInc <= cnMax
     sNFSpec = getNewFSpec(oFile.Name, sDstDir, nInc)
 Loop
If nInc > cnMax Then
  Else
   oFile.Move sNFSpec
End If

End If
Next
Wend

}





Dim oShell, frequency, sFile
Dim goFS    : Set goFS    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oSrcDir : Set oSrcDir = goFS.GetFolder("C:\Temp1")
Dim sDstDir : sDstDir     = "C:\Temp2"
Dim oFile, nInc, sNFSpec

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Temp1") 
Set fc = f.Files  

frequency  = 10 * 1000 
Const cnMax = 99


WScript.Sleep frequency

 theDate = Year(Now()) _
       & Right(String(2,"0") & month(Now()),2) _ 
       & Right(String(2,"0") & Day(Now()),2) 


 For Each f1 in fc 
  If right(lcase(f1.name),4) = ".pdf" then 
 theBaseName = fso.GetBaseName(f1.name)
 theExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(f1.Name) 
 f1.Move(fso.GetParentFolderName(f1.path) & "\" & theBaseName & "_" & EID & "_"    &          theDate & "." & theExtension) 
  End If
  Next

 For Each oFile In oSrcDir.Files
 If right(lcase(oFile.name),4) = ".pdf" Then 
  nInc = 0
  sNFSpec = getNewFSpec(oFile.Name, sDstDir, nInc)
  Do While goFS.FileExists(sNFSpec) And nInc <= cnMax
     sNFSpec = getNewFSpec(oFile.Name, sDstDir, nInc)
 Loop
If nInc > cnMax Then
  Else
   oFile.Move sNFSpec
End If

End If
Next
Wend

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution would be to run your task from another script which itself run "forever" (an abstraction).

```
Dim oShell, frequency, sFile

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
frequency  = 10 * 1000  '10 Seconds (just for example)
sFile      = "task.vbs" 'the script you want to run

While True  'make infinite cycle
    WScript.Sleep frequency
    oShell.Run sFile
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution [Panayot Karabakalov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15467604/1630171) proposed could also be integrated into the existing script:

```
'...

While True
  For Each oFile In oSrcDir.Files
    '...
  Next
  WScript.Sleep 30000 'milliseconds
Wend

'...
```

Another variant would be to use an unconditional `Do ... Loop` instead of `While True ... Wend`:

```
'...

Do
  For Each oFile In oSrcDir.Files
    '...
  Next
  WScript.Sleep 30000 'milliseconds
Loop

'...
```

Comment: Indeed Thanks a lot both for your answers, meanwhile I found the second script somewhere else, all by myself ;)

Comment: But the script has evolved now and if anyone could help on this one it would be great... The VBScript here below looks for PDF files every 10 Sec only and if found, he RENAMES all PDF files ADDING the DATE and the ExternalID found in the table index from the DB Index.mdb according to the Name Column. It works fine when I type into the SQL query 'test' but RENAMES every PDF files with the same EID, ExternalID thus. I would like help to first CHECK if the index.mdb exists, IF it does Then Get For Each File EID thus External ID and RENAME each Files accordingly .

Comment: Actually the Script evolved and it would be nice to keep track of that script on the same page...

Comment: Ansgar, I foud if db exists, all I need is to define a variable in the SQL statement to change accordingly every files. I get the same ExternalID for Every file...  So a For each file already exits but I can't get it into SQL statement in place of NAME...